# Pass blob URL from website to Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am struggling to use a blob URL from my website inside my Chrome extension's background page. That is, I create create the blob URL using URL.createObjectURL from an in-memory Blob instance on my website, then pass that URL to the extension (using the chrome.runtime.connect API). However, upon reading from that URL inside the extension using fetch(...) I get this error:

```
Fetch API cannot load blob:http://localhost:4200/a7188b44-f80e-4bfd-a63a-4a92f2f48424.
URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.
```

Is this something that I can fix by amending the CSP inside the extension's manifest? Basically, I want to avoid serializing the Blob's content and sending it to the extension using postMessage. This is probably slow and worse, causes some substantial "memory throughput", which is something that Chrome likes to crash on.

Comment: https://crbug.com/937576 might be related.

Comment: Do you simply fetch(url) or do you add some headers/parameters?

Comment: So far I just use fetch(bloburl), ie., without adding any request headers. Will try tinkering with the "Origin" header, not sure if that's possible in an extension's background script (don't think so).


And thanks for pointing to the open issue. Didn't see this one before. Assuming that setting the "Origin" header won't work, I guess I will need to look for alternatives that avoid serializing the blob.

Comment: In this regard: I was wondering if I can somehow use a content script to use the window.postMessage API (which - unlike the chrome.runtime.* messaging APIs - allows transferable ArrayBuffers). My idea is that the webseite calls window.postMessage, ie., posts to itself, which a content script (acting as a proxy) can intercept, then call postMessage again to the extension's background page.

Comment: Here's an idea. You can add an iframe that points to an extension page allowed via web_accessible_resources, do iframe.contentWindow.postMessage in the content script, then inside the iframe you can share the data directly with the background page via chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage because the iframe will have full access to chrome API. Or you can process things right inside the iframe.

Comment: Fantastic - this might work! For now, I've been serialising the data that I send to the background page as base64 strings, which is clearly not ideal.

I even wonder if - with the approach you suggest - I could use a single SharedArrayBuffer that is shared between my website, the <iframe> and the background page. That would be pretty amazing!